In the movie Source Code, how was Colter Stevens able to "be" specifically Sean Fentress?
I might be missing something, but in the movie Source Code, how was Colter Stevens able to "be" specifically Sean Fentress? I feel like the movie hand-waved the details of how the Source Code system worked when explaining the human brain has an 8-minute memory and how Colter Stevens was physically similar to Sean Fentress, but the movie did not explain how the Source Code system was able to "connect" to Sean Fentress specifically. Did I miss something?
For example, did Sean Fentress die on the train, but his body and brain were intact enough such that the military could scan his brain (with an MRI or similar) into the Source Code system?  Was Sean Fentress actually still alive, in a coma, or his body otherwise hooked up to the Source Code system (i.e. in a similar container as Colter Stevens was in)?
I know these are just hypothetical theories, and not answers, I'm just wondering if the movie (or the director) had any sort of explanation along these lines.

I can safely say that you didn't miss anything in the movie--they don't say where or how they got Sean's eight-minute brain black box.

@Exal Thanks, FWIW I would accept your comment as an answer!

"I feel like the movie hand-waved the details of how the Source Code system worked when explaining the [deceased] human brain has an 8-minute memory and how Colter Stevens was physically similar to Sean Fentress, but the movie did not explain how the Source Code system was able to "connect" to Sean Fentress specifically." 'Hand-waved' is about accurate!

Sean, in our timeline, is dead, along with everyone else.

so as you can see from the script, they say he had some compatibilities, and his head was intact (so theres activity that can be read and used and plugged into the system).
Clearly they had a truck with all the gear ready and plugged him in.
Although not said, its possible they did this a few times until they found someone compatible, as I think its unlikely they would know before hand.
So, yes, some hand-wavery about how they found Sean in the first place, but once they did, 'hey! he's compatible! plug him in!'...

did Sean Fentress die on the train,

Yes, in the initial bombing, in the primary timeline, Sean died. In all subsequent timelines that branch off each time they activate the machine, Sean is killed off each time (and is replaced by Colter). (The director pretty much said this in a Q and A)

but his body and brain were intact enough such that the military could scan his brain (with an MRI or similar) into the Source Code system?

Yes, his brain was intact,

Was Sean Fentress actually still alive, in a coma, or his body otherwise hooked up to the Source Code system (i.e. in a similar container as Colter Stevens was in)?

Apparently only his head, so that was plugged in, but by comparison, Colter has a lot more 'left' of him that allows him to build up his simulation of himself, his personality, retain his memories, and be aware. When you see Colter in his machine (in real life), he has enough of him that functions, presumably there is not enough of Sean to do that.
Sean seems to be an active 'body part' that functions but has no awareness, and functions as a telephone 'receiver' or perhaps just the 'socket', as opposed to a person on the other end of the telephone to receive and talk back - Sean doesn't have enough of himself left to do that, he's dead in every other way.
In the script (I don't recall if its seen in the movie) Seans head is plugged in the truck at the bomb site.

I know these are just hypothetical theories, and not answers, I'm just wondering if the movie (or the director) had any sort of explanation along these lines.

The writer Ben Ripley, seems to have come up with this, Duncan Jones, director (Moon, Mute) came later and added touches like humor, and possibly the additional timeline scenarios played out at the end (as that is not in Ripleys script).
How Sean is targeted as the only one to be at the other end of the line for Colter does not seem to have been brought up however.
Note: I see that the movie skips the corpse scene, which, although ghastly, might have made it a bit more obvious that a bit of dead Sean was plugged in. - instead they kind of gloss over it with:

Of all the passengers aboard, he was your best link.
You two share compatibility in terms of gender, body-size, and your synaptic maps.

https://www.sellingyourscreenplay.com/wp-content/uploads/screenplay/scripts/Source-Code.pdf

Indeed, it doesn't make much sense that a brain imprint would give you anything except what the person experienced, much less access to the whole world around you in that eight minutes.  (My idea was that the technology accesses a soul imprint, rather than a brain one.)
